# Forms of the verb "to be."

Tags: verbs

I was just typing up a document in MS word and it seemed to take umbrage with the following:

> Key tasks tackled by this group are understanding and allaying fears,
>   determining suitable and unsuitable use cases and weighing advantages
>   and disadvantages for certain classes.

Word underlined the word "understanding" and instead suggested I should try and use the simplest form of the verb: understand.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Word doesn't understand English syntax.

Comment: It should read "to be tackled" or "key tasks tackled.... were", and perhaps add a colon before understanding since the rest is essentially a list.

Comment: @Misneac *Key tasks tackled...are* is correct syntax. Compare: *Books read in this class are...*

Comment: @User1 I think you're right that it is correct, but there definitely needs to be some sort of punctuation after "are". It seems awkward otherwise.

Comment: No there does not need to be some punctuation after *are* except the commas in the list.

Comment: I ran it through the spelling and grammar checker and it got the all clear. I can't see anything wrong with the participle "understanding", or the sentence in general, except that I might consider treating the 3 participial clauses as a list by inserting a colon before "understanding" and then replacing the comma with a semi-colon. But I'd say that was optional rather than obligatory.

Comment: Decide whether you want to speak/write English or MS Word. ;-)

Comment: The linguist Geoffrey K. Pullum has argued that they [*grammar checking algorithms*] are generally so inaccurate as to do more harm than good: "for the most part, accepting the advice of a computer grammar checker on your prose will make it much worse, sometimes hilariously incoherent." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar_checker